# Using RegOpenKey and RegEnumKey in dynamic QT with MSVC2010

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, linker, linker-errors

I want to use 2 winapi functions for registry access, as stated.
I have QT 5.3.2 with QT Creator 3.2.0, MSVC2010 build, Windows SDK v7.1 and debugging tools installed.

`windows.h` is included in my project and both functions are seen, but linker fails with

> usb_part.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegEnumKeyW@16 referenced in function "bool __cdecl GetUsbName(class QString &)" (?GetUsbName@@YA_NAAVQString@@@Z)
>
> usb_part.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyW@12 referenced in function "bool __cdecl GetUsbName(class QString &)" (?GetUsbName@@YA_NAAVQString@@@Z)

I suppose it tries to link those functions dynamically (hense the "__imp"), how can I set it to link against a static `.lib` file? Or, if that is not possible with dynamically built QT, how do I link those to `.dll`?

---

UPD:
Tried these:

```
LIBS += -ladvapi32
LIBS += AdvAPI32.Lib
LIBS += "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\AdvAPI32.Lib"
```

to no avail

---

UPD2:
Problem was in QT not recreating makefiles after changes to `.pro`. After I deleted makefiles, `LIBS += -ladvapi32` worked fine. Thought that "Clean project" does that, but it turns out that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your .pro file

```
LIBS += -lAdvapi32
```

or

```
LIBS += Advapi32.lib
```

After that run `qmake` and `build` again.

[**Update**] It may be needed to remove generated makefiles manually and recreated them with `qmake` run again.

Comment: Tried that, and different versions of it (like specifying the full path), still no result (see update)

Comment: try to remove generated makefiles manually and then to create them again by running qmake ... or you can try to find manually that libs are specified in the generated makefiles to not remove them manually

Comment: OK, manually deleting makefiles seems to have helped here, `LIBS += -ladvapi32` works now. I just wonder why QT doesn't delete them on "Clean project"

Comment: Qt Creator distinguish qmake step of building and building of generated makefiles. Because makefiles are generated by qmake, cleaning doesn't affect them, it's needed to run qmake from Qt Creator build menu to update makefiles. If the makefiles not get updated (and I had such issue on Windows pretty often too) it looks like qmake bug.